# Exoplayer- how to immediately trigger a BehindLiveWindowException after pausing/resuming a live stream outside live window

Tags: android, exoplayer

My live window is approximately 10 minutes, my buffer is about 30 seconds. If I pause the stream for longer than 10 minutes then resume, the player will play the buffered data for ~30 secs before throwing a `BehindLiveWindowException`.

Instead, is there a way to anticipate ahead of the buffer for a possible `BehindLiveWindowException` so that we can receive the error straight away? I've tried looking online but there's very little on this topic.

Comment: Solution: I managed to achieve this by listening for `onTimelineChanged` events. From this, we can get the earliest window start time of the timeline and immediately jump to the latest live point if the user is behind this window.

Comment: Hi can you please further elaborate on how to do this onTimelineChanged.

Comment: Left an answer on the post :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    override fun onTimelineChanged(timeline: Timeline, reason: Int) {
    if (timeline.isEmpty) {
      earliestLiveWindowTime = LIVE_WINDOW_UNSET
      return
    }

    val window = timeline.getWindow(0, timelineWindow, 0)
    earliestLiveWindowTime = window.windowStartTimeMs
  }
```

Regarding the above code, `earliestLiveWindowTime` will be the earliest time available of the live window. When resuming after having paused for a while, if the player position is a lower value than this `earliestLiveWindowTime` value, we know that we're behind the live window so can throw a `BehindLiveWindowException` at this point.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I will give it a go.